# Can $.getJSON work with a JSONC file containing comments?

Tags: jquery, json

For those who don't know, JSONC is a version of JSON that supports comments.

Anyway, I have a jQuery script that works fine with a JSON file, and if I rename it to JSONC it still works as long as there aren't any comments (which are JSONC's claim to fame). But I need comments to help less-tech-savvy people maintain these files in the long run.

This works fine:

```
$.getJSON('filename.jsonc', function(json) {do stuff}
```

With the JSONC file containing:

```
[{"name":"something"}]
```

But if I add a comment, it stops working:

```
[{"name":"something" // comment}]
[{"name":"something" /* comment */}]
```

I'm guessing that there's something I need to do to get the script to ignore the comments, but I haven't been able to figure out what that is. Do I abandon $.getJSON entirely and do this with Javascript, or is there a way to stick with it?

I'd appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

PS: I've seen the "_comment" trick, and it's not flexible enough for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

jquery´s `$.getJSON` will automatically parse JSON-encoded remote data.

As your remote data is not valid json anymore it will fail.

You have multiple options now. The best probably is to encode the data on the serverside using for example the jsonc php package or npm jsonc-parser or similiar, so your client js code can still work with $.getJSON. Or you just make a regular $.ajax or anykind of xmlhttprequest and try to decode the jsonc to json with client js. Should be also doable with jsonc-parser